# Search for question mark with Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex, special-characters

I'm new to Regular Expressions and I have some questions in my codes.

I tried this but both return false

```
string pattern = @"\?!";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("!", pattern));
// false
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("?", pattern));
// false
```

But when I did it this way both return true

```
string pattern = @"\!?";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("!", pattern));
// true
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("?", pattern));
// true
```

So my question is.

1. Is the order of `?` matters?
2. How does `?` work in Regular Expressions?

Comment: `?` is different to `\?`. The fair comparison is `!\?` vs `\?!` -- which will return true for the inputs `"!?"` and `"?!"` respectively, and false for everything else. `!?` means "a `!` zero or one times", `!\?` means "a `!` followed by a `?`"

Comment: Unescaped `?` makes the pattern it modifies match *1 or 0 times*, i.e. makes it optional.

Comment: it seems you're looking for `@"!|\?"` which means a `!` _or_ a `?`.

Comment: @RenéVogt Thank you! That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah, I see why it becomes optional when I put `?` after `!`, thank you for linking the post!